# Conditionally add a property when augmenting a module

Tags: typescript

I'm using module augmentation to add additional properties to an interface from a library as so:

```
declare module "library" {
    export interface Props<
        LibraryObject      
    > {
        handleDateChange: LibraryObject extends MyCustomObject ? (arg: Date) => void : never
    } 
}
```

However, now the compiler complains if the `handleDateChange` is missing from any object that implements the `Props<LibraryObject>` interface. I could make the property optional (e.g. `handleDateChange?:`) but then I need to explicitly check it whenever working with `MyCustomObject`.

Is there any way to conditonally add the property to the interface when augmenting the module? E.g. only add the `handleDateChange` property if `LibraryObject extends MyCustomObject`?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @zenly - it's what the library's author recommends. https://react-select.com/typescript#custom-select-props